# Merging layers and excluding some of the products in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, polygon-creation, union

When merging two layers of polygons so that they produce a third layer where no polygon contains another polygon, I find that the product contains some very small polygons, almost too small to see.

[image]

Presumably, this is due to boundaries that are almost the same but have a very slight difference.

What could possibly be done to prevent this?

I was using the latest QGIS's `Vector/Geospatial/Union` option but would try any open-source tool.

Do you think [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402905/smoothing-polygons-to-fill-in-any-indents-that-are-less-that-a-certain-width-i) question has answers that might be the solution?

Comment: Try this here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385096/88814

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the "[Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer)" tool by specifying the tolerance distance before "Union".

In the example, the green layer is snapped to the red layer so that the gap between the layers does not result in a small polygon.

[image]